# Shell Script to remove duplicate entries from file

Tags: file, shell, duplicates

I would like to remove duplicate entries from a file. The file looks like this:

```
xyabcd1:5!b4RlH/IgYzI:cvsabc
xyabcd2:JXfFZCZrL.6HY:cvsabc
xyabcd3:mE7YHNejLCviM:cvsabc
xyabcd1:5!b4RlH/IgYzI:cvsabc
xyabcd4:kQiRgQTU20Y0I:cvsabc
xyabcd2:JXfFZCZrL.6HY:cvsabc
xyabcd1:5!b4RlH/IgYzI:cvsabc
xyabcd2:JXfFZCZrL.6HY:cvsabc
xyabcd4:kQiRgQTU20Y0I:cvsabc
xyabcd2:JXfFZCZrL.6HY:cvsabc
```

How can I remove the duplicates from this file by using shell script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the sort manpage:

> -u, --unique
>             with -c, check for strict ordering; without -c, output only the first of an equal run

```
sort -u yourFile
```

should do.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to change the order of the input file, you can do:

```
$ awk '!v[$0]{ print; v[$0]=1 }' input-file
```

or, if the file is small enough (less than 4 billion lines, to ensure that no line is repeated 4 billion times), you can do:

```
$ awk '!v[$0]++' input-file
```

Depending on the implementation of awk, you may not need to worry about the file being less than 2^32 lines long.  The concern is that if you see the same line 2^32 times, you may overflow an integer in the array value, and the 2^32nd instance (or 2^31st) of the duplicate line will be output a second time.  In reality, this is highly unlikely to be an issue!

Answer (score 0):

@shadyabhi answer is correct, if the output needs to be redirected to a different file use:

sort -u inFile -o outFile